# sqlalchemy: declarative base how to import own classes

Tags: python, class, orm, sqlalchemy

I am just starting with sqlalchemy orm. Basically, I am following the example from [this tutorial](http://pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/). While the code presented there works fine, my code ends in an error.

I have a script defining all declarations:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sqldcl
import sqlalchemy.orm as sqlmap

engine = sql.create_engine('postgresql://username@localhost/dbname')

Base = sqldcl.declarative_base(metadata=sql.MetaData(engine, schema='schemaname'))

class Creators(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'creators'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    entity1 = sql.Column(sql.Integer)
    entity2 = sql.Column(sql.Unicode())


class Organizations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organizations'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fk_creators = sql.Column(sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey('creators.id'))
    creators = sqlmap.relationship(Creators)
    entity4 = sql.Column(sql.Integer)
    entity5 = sql.Column(sql.Unicode())

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This script runs without error. But if I now want to insert something into my database with the following script...

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy_declarative import Creators, Base, Organizations

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username@localhost/dbname')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()

new_creator = Creators(entity1='111')
session.add(new_creator)
session.commit()


new_organization = Organizations(entity4='111', entity5='Blabla', creators=new_creator)
session.add(new_organization)
session.commit()
```

...I get the following error:

```
from sqlalchemy_declarative import Creators, Base, Organizations
ImportError: cannot import name 'Creators'
```

I just cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is just a path issue, make sure that file is in your python path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Ok. I got it. It really was a path/naming issue and nothing wrong with my code. Thanks @reptilicus for putting me on the right track.